# helping hand for sql server resources

Tags: sql-server, syntax

I'm just getting into SQL-SERVER, so forgive me if this is a basic question.

I need help, recently work on database programming, For my query development, to understand complex query, to can optimized syntax, I need guideline/good resources. Give me a helping hand to increase my knowledge in sql field.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my favourite article for beginners: http://www.sqlmag.com/article/tsql3/t-sql-101-lesson-1

10 articles in total, you will be a pro in no time.

Comment: thanks ........for reply.......is there any best book?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Itzik Ben-Gan](http://www.sql.co.il/) books (Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Fundamentals, Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Querying, Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Programming) is very applicable for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was very satisfied with [Murach SQL Server 2008 for Developers](http://www.amazon.ca/Murachs-SQL-Server-2008-Developers/dp/1890774510/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1327498530&sr=8-1) which was used to teach us database programming in college. It will take you through everything from the basics to intermediate programming and includes functions, views, indexes, aggregate queries, dynamic SQL, stored procedures and XML.

The layout is great with detailed descriptions are on the left-hand page and summaries, examples and tables are on the right; this makes it very useful as a reference book after you are done learning the basics.